# How can I load jar files for debugging in Jython?

Tags: java, jar, jython

How can I load jar files for debugging in Jython?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the JAR file to sys.path .

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\lib\guava-12.jar')
from com.google.common.io import *
```

Answer (score 2):

add them on the classpath !

the answer says it all ;-)